# QGIS Not responding - qgis-bin.exe or qgis-ltr-bin.exe not responding

Tags: qgis, error, windows

In QGIS, when I double-click on a layer to display its properties (or even right-click to select Properties), QGIS stops responding giving an error message "qgis-ltr-bin.exe is not responding". Was running QGIS 3.10, then uninstalled it and installed QGIS 3.16 Hannover. Problem persists giving the error message "qgis-bin.exe is not responding". I realize my question is similar to previous questions, but have been unable to find the solution to this problem. The problem only started last week.

Is it possible that the problem is related to missing .dll files? Tried running the qgiscrashhandler.exe, but the software is unable to run due to missing Qt5Gui.dll (QGIS 3.10) or Qt5Widgets.dll (QGIS 3.16).

Answer (score 1):

What I did was delete my user profile found on my C-disk.
`C:\Users\mmv490\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default`

And made a new default profile by renaming my old default profile.

In this way some bug is avoided by relocating your settings and the properties window can be opened again.

Comment: Did you delete the folder named **default** or the **profiles.ini** configuration file? There are several folders within the folder named **default**. What steps did you take to make a new default profile if you deleted the old default profile? Thanks in advance

Comment: The profiles.ini just contains a path to the profile folder, so you may just as well move that to an "old" folder, along with the default folder if you want to erase the profile. It will be recreated. But erasing the profile did not help for me. Every now and then QGIS stops responding, primarily when I return focus to QGIS from another program, or opening and even closing internal dialog windows inside QGIS.